# Python: How to delete the folders called trash that are older than 3 months

Tags: python

I'm looking to create a script that will look through specific directories and its subdirectories, and if it contains a folder called trash, and it is older than 3 months it will delete that trash folder and its contents.

The code i have already tried is shown below. It contains a couple of options of how to get the time of 3 months. I have also used os.walk to try to traverse the directories, but i have not managed to target just the trash folders and then remove them.

```
import os, sys, time
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
from subprocess import call
import path 



now = time.time()
cutoff = now - (30)#(91 * 86400)
three_months = datetime.today() - timedelta(0,0,0,0,0,1)

path = '/users/shoot_station_5/documents/folderfordeletetest/'



for root, d_names, f_names in os.walk(path):
    print (root, d_names, f_names)
    for _dir in d_names:
        time_thing = os.path.getmtime(os.path.join (root, _dir))
        time_thing1 = datetime.fromtimestamp(time_thing)
        if time_thing1 <= three_months and _dir == 'trash':
        # fname = os.path.join(d_names, _dir)
        # if time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(os.path.join (root, _dir))) < cutoff:
            print ('good')
```

Comment: Would the trash folder potentially be an arbitrary number of levels down the parent folder? If so, you might want to build a recursive implementation.

Comment: yes it could be about 2 or 3 levels down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code delete a directory called trash that are older than 3 months and all its contents.

```
import os
import datetime
import shutil

def Delete_Folder(filesPath,No_of_Days):
    for root, d_names, f_names in os.walk(filesPath):
        for _dir in d_names:
            if str(_dir).lower() == "trash":
                DName = os.path.join (root, _dir)
                today = datetime.datetime.today()
                modified_date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(DName))
                duration = today - modified_date

                if (duration.days > No_of_Days):
                    shutil.rmtree(DName)


# Call Function
NoDays = 90
filesPath = r"C:\Sample"
Delete_Folder(filesPath,NoDays)
```